# Display columns based on the Choice from the Drop Down Menu in List

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a List with 7 columns.

Out of that I have a Gate column (Choice) which has 5 options (Design, Verification, ... )

My requirement is when i select each option based on the select it should show few more columns.

Ex: If i select Design from the Drop Down Menu (Gate Column) by default it should show all the other 6 columns and added to that it should show few other columns

New Column 1

When i select Verification it should display another set of columns (by default all the 6 columns should be displayed)

Note: All the 7 Columns (Including Gate Column) are standard and should be displayed for any of the 5 choices through the drop down menu from Gate Column

How this can be achieved.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What do you mean with "should show few more columns"? Your list has 7 columns. Show all the other 6 columns and then "few other columns" -- ?????

Comment: Yes Teylyn, 
Show all the columns and then few other columns based on the drop down selection.
Basically, I want to have all the data stored so that I can export it.

Comment: Edit your question and provide a concrete example. Do you want the list form to show certain field controls based on a value of another field? So, how many columns does your list have? Which columns do you want to show, based on which condition?

Comment: Hi teylyn, Thanks I will get back with the complete requirement